# what is correct way to include foundation 5 in a wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress theme from my Foundation website.

what is the correct way to enqueue the javascript files I need in functions.php?
I found many tutorial online but none is 100%

this is the way I did but for some reason my top bar toggle doesn't work, I assume I'm not including jquery in the correct way.

I have to say that I don't know anything about PHP and I'm trying to find examples that would work in my case with no luck..

```
<?php

function devocean_script()  
{  
    //register scripts for our theme  
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/jquery.js', 
    false );
    wp_register_script('foundation-mod',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizer.js', 
false );  
wp_register_script('foundation-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', 
    true );  



//enqueue scripts for our theme
wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-mod' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');  
wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-main' );
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'devocean_script' );  

?>
```

It would be great if somwone could give me a hint.. I'm really stucked here and need to keep moving..

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use foundation 5 with wordpress,please note the following.

1. modernizr should load on wp-head.

```html
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/vendor/modernizr.js', array(), '', false );
```

or through CDN network like this

```html
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js', array(), '', false );
```

2. Load jquery at footer

```html
 function jqloading()
  {
   
 wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'); 
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
  add_action('wp_footer','jqloading');
```

3. enque foundation js and foundation css files

```html
wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/foundation.min.css' );
```

4. Make sure that foundation is initialised by adding this code in footer.ph

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery(document).foundation();
  
 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without deregistering jquery?

Plus you should have jquery loaded in the footer by passing `true` as the last argument to the `wp_reqister_script` function. Of course this only works if you have the call to `wp_footer` in the right place in your theme.